# What do you call what amounts to a modern hybrid between a sneaker and a high top moccasin?

Tags: winter, boots, winter-walking

Thirty odd years ago there was a fad for shoes generically called snow joggers.  It was a super lightweight boot in appearence -- usually 6-8" tall, but with a very light construction throughout.  They were somewhat wide to accommodate more socks.

They had essentially no ankle support -- or maybe the amount of support of a canvas top runner.

As a fashion item they were cheap.  Typically about $20, and they would last a year or two -- about the same as pair of Walmart sneakers.  Tops were made of nylon fabric, probably a little lighter than pack cloth.

Even at the time they came in different styles.  At one extreme were "Moon boots" with a thick layer of foam insulation. These were not considered 'snow joggers'

Most were two ply fabric with about 1/4" of Thinsulite.  Any insulation on a boot makes it much harder to dry.

- They were easy to dry around the campfire.
- They were light -- light enough to jog behind a dog sled all day.
- They were tall enough that you didn't need gaiters to keep the snow out.
- They were cheap enough that if you melted on drying it, you didn't cry too hard.  (I told people on my trips, "don't buy black -- you can't see it toast")

I can't find the equivalent now.  Everything is either a boot, is designed to provide lots of support, is heavy, and clunky to jog in; or is a duckboot, with in effect a 10 or 12" boot dipped 3 inches into rubber; or is stuffed with undryable foam.

Sorel makes a large line of very clunky footwear. Great for standing around at -40.  No good for running.

Various running brands make what they call winter running shoes, but they don't keep the snow out, and are not sized for extra socks.

Hunting stores have winter boots but again, they tend to be heavy, expensive and hard to dry.

I'm pretty sure they must exist, I just don't know the right name.  Every time I use 'boots' I get stuff that is heavy.  Every time I use moccasin I get stuff that amounts to indoor slippers.  Every time I search for 'snow joggers' I get puffy things.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://www.amazon.com/Rubber-Duck-Snow-Jogger-Boots/dp/B000KU1F0O) exactly what you describe? It even says "Part sneaker and part snow boot" in the description.

Comment: @GabrielC. - although it isn't currently in stock and Amazon doesn't know when it will be!

Comment: Foam insulated. Impossible to dry.  Edited question to make specific.

Comment: I don't know, but I want a pair.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're still called [snow joggers](https://www.google.ca/search?q=snow+joggers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm-YWL7OPeAhWRG3wKHYteBmcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=969).

Comment: @ShemSeger   Alas too well insulated.

Comment: A year or two for Walmart sneakers is way over stating their lifetime.  It took only 7 "wearings" before the soles of my Walmart sneakers started to come apart.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found anything yet, but have two partial solutions.

#### Sneakers + gaiters.

For this I need to buy sneakers in at least 1 full size larger, and go extra wide.  My intent is to go in wearing two pairs of thick socks.  The gaiters keep snow out of the shoe.

Ideally the sneaker part is a simple canvas high top that will be easy to dry around the fire.

#### DIY moccasins.

There are various plans around the internet.  While most of the plans are for the traditional leather, I don't see any reason that I couldn't use nylon coated nylon pack cloth for the lowers and uncoated for the uppers.  The biggest issue here is how fast the sole wears out, and the lack of traction.

Comment: Would you be able to build on canvas sport shoes, like the original sneakers? Cut of the tops leaving enough to sew your top to?

Comment: Thought about that, but I have wide feet, and have trouble finding shoes wide enough to wear two pairs of socks in.